# Save/Open dialog is not appear while trying download by FileResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have a problem with downloading files from my application. When I call a method `DownloadVacationProposal` and returning the file nothing happens. Save/Open dialog in browser is not appearing.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
downloadVacationProposal: function () {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "Presence/DownloadVacationProposal",
        });
    }
```

and C# which I found here:

```
public FileResult DownloadVacationProposal()
    {

        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/proposal.doc");
        string contentType = "application/msword";


        return File(filePath, contentType, "proposal.doc");
    }
```

I'm probably missing something, but I don't know what, so please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens when you use GET instead of POST?

Comment: The same. Nothing happens.

Comment: did you debug this in the browser? Is the javascript function being called? Does the request arrive at the Action Method? Is the Action method executed? What's in the response?

Comment: you will find this extremely helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post, if you you cannot transform you Angular call in to required, return in the first step an <a href='website/Presence/DownloadVacationProposaNewl'> anchor with the path to a new controller witch return a file (mime type), and from javascript click on the anchor.

Comment: Ok, problem resolved. Just used HTML tag. This is enough. Thanks for all of you!